Most direct way to check if array contains any non-null values
Currently doing this:
cardinality(filter(my_array, x -> x is not null)) != 0

Is there a more direct way?

Yes, for Trino (since 317 version)/Presto(since 0.230 version) you can use any_match:
any_match(my_array, x -> x is not null)


Try
EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM UNNEST(my_array) AS x WHERE x IS NOT NULL)


How is this "a more direct way"?
